# Generate random string in MySql stored function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, data-conversion

I need generate a random string in MySql stored function.
I solved this problem, but my solution seems too ugly and too slow:

```
CREATE FUNCTION generate_salt() RETURNS varchar(11) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE res varchar(11) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE salt_sym varchar(2);
    DECLARE tmp_res varchar(20) DEFAULT'';
    DECLARE salt_len int DEFAULT 10;

    WHILE salt_len > 0 DO
      SET salt_sym = HEX(FLOOR(32 + RAND() * 96));
      SET tmp_res = CONCAT(tmp_res, salt_sym), salt_len = salt_len - 1;
    END WHILE;
    set res=UNHEX(tmp_res);
    RETURN res;
END
```

This code converts the random integers from a diapason [32, 126] to hexadecimal string and then converts the hexadecimal string to ascii-string using unhex() function.

Is there any way to convert a digit to ASCII character ( 0x30 => '0', 0x31=>'1', 0x32=> '2', etc.) without double (byte => hex 2-literal string => char) conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use:

```
return sha2(rand(), 256)
```

If you want more randomness, just concat multiple rand() calls.

Answer (score 0):

For generating random string, you can use `CHAR()` (to cast the integer to a character) and `MOD()` functions:

```
CHAR(65+MOD(ROUND(RAND()*100),26))
```